# "Property does not exist on type" using styled-components in .tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm attempting to incorporate Styled-Components into a React project using TypeScript. Constructing the component immediately highlights `div` with the error:

```
Property 'div' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/admin/node_modules/style-components/dist/index")'.ts(2339)
```

This is my code:

```
// App.tsx
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import styled from 'style-components'

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`

const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledDiv>
        <h1>Testing</h1>
      </StyledDiv>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Strangely, if I create that styled component in its own `.ts` file, export it, and import it into `.App.tsx` it will work just fine. Are styled components only meant to be imported and not used directly in a `.tsx` file?

My `package.json` file for informational purposes.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did more testing and created a new component file and immediately I was met with a type error. I started over with a new project folder and used Yarn instead of NPM (which is what I was previously used to). The problem hasn't shown up again.